# Parsing / splitting with Regex that can embed itself

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing

Trying to match & parse a syntax string with RegEx. Current generation syntax is:

```
${name:val1=val2,val3=val4}
```

the colon and everything after it is optional
you must have the post colon stuff in pairs, ie, you can't have just val3=, and of course, commas must be "right"

Current RegEx is working perfectly:

```
(\${([A-Za-z]+)(:([A-Za-z]+)=([A-Za-z0-9]+)(,([A-Za-z]+)=([A-Za-z0-9]+))*)*})
```

Current Code, also working perfectly:

```
MatchCollection matches = _regEx.Matches("${a:b=c,d=e}");

foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("1) " + m.Value + " " + m.Groups[2].Value);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("1a) " + m.Groups[4].Value + " ==> " + m.Groups[5].Value);

    for (int nParam = 0; nParam < m.Groups[7].Captures.Count; nParam++)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups[7].Captures[nParam].Value) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups[8].Captures[nParam].Value))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("1b) " + m.Groups[7].Captures[nParam].Value + " ==> " + m.Groups[8].Captures[nParam].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

This displays:

```
    //1) ${a:b=c,d=e} a
    //1a) b ==> c
    //1b) d ==> e
```

That is exactly what I want. I want to know the "a" and I want to know each param pairs.

Ok, so now we come to 2nd generation syntax:

```
${name:val1=val2,val3=${name2:val1=val2}}
```

I.e. nested / recursive, whatever you want to call it.

So with that input, I'm trying to get something like:

```
    //1) ${a:b=c,d=e,f=${g}${h:i=j}} a
    //1a) b => c
    //1b) d => e
    //1b) f => ${g}${h:i=j}
```

Nested strings can be "infinitely" deep. In this particular case, as I parse "f", I'll know that it might have a nested string and I'll parse that out recursively (C# / regex) the same way I parse the top level now, so it will naturally recurse.

So I thought to just upgrade my regex to:

```
(\${([A-Za-z]+)(:([A-Za-z]+)=([A-Za-z0-9${}:=,]+)(,([A-Za-z${}:=,]+)=([A-Za-z0-9${}:=,]+))*)*})
```

All I did was add ${}:=, to the stuff allowed to the right of the = sign. So the complex test case works, but the simple one breaks as it doesn't know that c,d is within the same {} set.

So it seems like instead of adding the ${}:=, I need to embed the whole expression in itself somehow.

Also seems like balancing groups might work, but all the examples seem kinda crazy, and even worse, one simple example in VS2015 crashes the IDE / debugger. Works fine in 2013 LOL... I reported that bug to Microsoft though, but balancing groups might be out due to that bug.

Any ideas?

EDIT: This isn't working, not splitting out anything.

```
    Regex regEx = new Regex(@"\${(?>\${(?<c>)|}(?<-c>)|(?:(?!\${|}).)*)*(?(c)(?!))}");

    MatchCollection matches = regEx.Matches("${a:b=c,d=e,f=${g}}");

    foreach (Match m in matches)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(m.Value);

        int c1 = 0;
        foreach (Capture c in m.Captures)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("C" + c1 + " " + c.Value);
            c1++;
        }
        int g1 = 0;
        foreach (Group g in m.Groups)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("G" + g1 + " " + g.Value);
            g1++;
            int c2 = 0;
            foreach (Capture c in g.Captures)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GC" + c2 + "  " + c.Value);
                c2++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can suggest a regex to get overlapping nested substrings [`(?=(\${(?>\${(?<c>)|}(?<-c>)|(?:(?!\${|}).)*)*(?(c)(?!))}))`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3d(%5c%24%7b(%3f%3e%5c%24%7b(%3f%3cc%3e)%7c%7d(%3f%3c-c%3e)%7c(%3f%3a(%3f!%5c%24%7b%7c%7d).)*)*(%3f(c)(%3f!))%7d))&i=%24%7bname%3aval1%3dval2%2cval3%3d%24%7bname2%3aval1%3dval2%7d%7d) (the values are in `.Groups[1].Value`, multiple matches should be obtained with `Regex.Matches(str, rx).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)`). You might loop through the results and use current parsing regex on those that only have one `${...}`.

Comment: @stribizhev, this returns just the various ${...} portions, but it loses all the relationships. Like I need to know that f=${g}${h:i=j}, I don't need to know that ${g} is a substring at this point in the processing.

Comment: Ok, just use a non-lookahead version. Remove the initial `(?=(` and the last `))`. Then, you will have separate strings containing those with nested structures that you will be able to parse with the above leaving the first capture out (the whole match).

Comment: @stribizhev, please see the EDIT, doesn't work unless I misunderstood your explanation :).

Comment: Does it mean you will not have any `${g}`s inside `${g}`? Or can there be `"${a:b=c,d=e,f=${${g}}}"` and then you'd like to get `${${g}}`?

Comment: @stribizhev, no... string can be: "XXX${a:b=c,d=e,f=${g}}YYY${a:b=c,d=e,f=${g}}ZZZ", i.e. multiple "variables" in the string, so I want to get each *top level* ${...} portion and for each portion, I want the name (a),b equals c relationship, d equals e relationship and f=${g} relationship (i.e. the parameters). g can of course use the same syntax as the whole thing in nested fashion.

Comment: @stribizhev -- one clarification... the nested parts don't have to be parsed out at this level... so if you get ${a:b=${c:d=e}} for example, at this level, i just need to split out the a, b = ${c:d=e}.

Comment: Try [`(\${([A-Za-z]+)(:([A-Za-z]+)=([A-Za-z0-9]+)(,([A-Za-z]+)=((?:\${[^{}]+}|[A-Za-z0-9]+)*))*)*})`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5c%24%7b(%5bA-Za-z%5d%2b)(%3a(%5bA-Za-z%5d%2b)%3d(%5bA-Za-z0-9%5d%2b)(%2c(%5bA-Za-z%5d%2b)%3d((%3f%3a%5c%24%7b%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%2b%7d%7c%5bA-Za-z0-9%5d%2b)*))*)*%7d)&i=%24%7ba%3ab%3dc%2cd%3de%2cf%3d%24%7bg%7d%24%7bH%7d%7d)

Comment: @stribizhev... HOLY MOLY!! I think its working :) You are the regex king LOL... if you put your response in the answer, I can mark as answer and upvote you. Thanks a lot for the help! I did have to make one minor tweak and changed one of the * to a + (\${([A-Za-z]+)(:([A-Za-z]+)=([A-Za-z0-9]+)(,([A-Za-z]+)=((?:\${[^{}]+}|[A-Za-‌​z0-9]+)+))*)*}) as the * allowed ${a:b=c,d=,f=${g}}, but dropped the d= portion... by changing it to a +, it now just matches on the ${g} which isn't 100% ideal (only 99% haha). Is there a cool regex way to prevent it from picking up nested ones in the top level parse?

Comment: Ok, just give me 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(\${([A-Za-z]+)(:([A-Za-z]+)=([A-Za-z0-9]+)(,([A-Za-z]+)=((?:\${(?>\${(?<c>)|}(?<-c>)|(?:(?!\${|}).)*)*(?(c)(?!))}|[A-Za-‌​‌​z0-9]+)+))*)*})
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5c%24%7b(%5bA-Za-z%5d%2b)(%3a(%5bA-Za-z%5d%2b)%3d(%5bA-Za-z0-9%5d%2b)(%2c(%5bA-Za-z%5d%2b)%3d((%3f%3a%5c%24%7b(%3f%3e%5c%24%7b(%3f%3cc%3e)%7c%7d(%3f%3c-c%3e)%7c(%3f%3a(%3f!%5c%24%7b%7c%7d).)*)*(%3f(c)(%3f!))%7d%7c%5bA-Za-%e2%80%8c%e2%80%8b%e2%80%8c%e2%80%8bz0-9%5d%2b)%2b))*)*%7d)&i=%24%7ba%3ab%3dc%2cd%3de%2cf%3d%24%7bg%7d%24%7bH%7d%7d%0d%0aabc%24%7ba%3ab%3dc%2cd%3de%2cf%3dabc%24%7bg%3al%3d%24%7bm%7d%7dxyz%7d123)

The main point is the added `\${(?>\${(?<c>)|}(?<-c>)|(?:(?!\${|}).)*)*(?(c)(?!))}` subpattern (that matches nested `${...}` substrings) and the alternative group `(?:\${[^{}]+}|[A-Za-‌​‌​z0-9]+)+` created with that subpattern. The `+` requires at least one of the alternatives to be in the text.

Comment: I think you should reconsider the number of capturing groups. The easiest is to use `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` and turn the necessary numbered capturing groups to **named** ones.

Comment: Hmm.. I may have spoken too soon :(. It does work at one level of nesting, but doesn't match at multiple levels: abc${a:b=c,d=e,f=abc${g:l=${m}}xyz}123. It only picks up the inner most ${m}...

Comment: Use the balanced regex as the subpattern then. See my edit.

Comment: I think (\${([A-Za-z]+)(:([A-Za-z]+)=([A-Za-z0-9]+)(,([A-Za-z]+)=((?:\${([A-Za-z]+)(:([A-Za-z]+)=([A-Za-z0-9${}]+)(,([A-Za-z0-9${}]+)=([A-Za-z0-9${}]+))*)*}|[A-Za-‌​z0-9]+)+))*)*}) might be working :). Thanks again!

Comment: I implemented the named groups as you suggested. Makes the code a bit cleaner :).